# Uploading Photos to iCloud on iPhone 4

Tags: ios, icloud, photos, iphone

My iPhone 4 has many photos. I would like to have them all uploaded to iCloud, but I don’t have an option to enable iCloud Photo Library.

How can I upload all my photos to iCloud?

Comment: Instead of the hardware model, can you please specify the iOS version you are using?

Comment: @PeterWhite I don’t know if you got a notification of my response, but I updated my answer with steps for exporting your photos to your iMac.

Answer (score 3):

The iPhone 4 is limited to iOS 7.1.2, which does not support iCloud Photo Library.

If your iPhone gets backed up to iCloud, then your photos are in iCloud, although you cannot view them at iCloud.com, or from another Apple device.

If you want your photos synced to iCloud Photo Library so that they can be viewed from iCloud.com and from other Apple devices, you will need to backup your iPhone, upgrade to a newer iPhone that supports at least iOS 8, and restore your backup onto that new iPhone. From there, you can enable iCloud Photo Library and sync your photos across all your Apple devices.

Another option is to export all your photos to a computer, then upload them to iCloud through a web browser at iCloud.com. To do this, plug your iPhone into your Mac, then press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> and enter `Image Capture`. Select your iPhone, the photos you want to `Import` onto your Mac, and a folder. Do note that this is a manual process you would need to repeat on a regular basis.

The easiest option would be for you to upgrade to a new iPhone and use iCloud Photo Library.

Comment: Many thanks. The iOS version is, of course 7.1.2 (on my existing iPhone 4).The advice is clear and clearly helpful. But it's much more practical for me to use the second option rather than at this point upgrade the iPhone. So all I now need to know or find out is, how to export the iPhone 4 photos to my iMac?

Comment: I had already updated my answer with steps for importing your photos onto your Mac 

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem. What's App is no longer supported on my boyfriends iphone 4 so we had a panic buy of a pre-owned iphone 6 this afternoon. I'm transferring everything over for him but there is no option to upload photos to icloud.

I've just started to try something. It's a little bit time consuming but it's working.

Basically I'm sending batches of photos from his old iphone 4 (connected to wi-fi) to his new iphone 6 via the 'shared' cloud shaped icon option at the bottom of the camera roll page in the iphone photos library.

When you select the 'shared' cloud icon for the first time, it tells you to give the shared album a stream name so I just called it part 1. Press Next. I then put my boyfriends email address in so basically I was sending it from him to him! Then select 'create' in the top right hand corner.

It will take you to your photos where you tick the ones you want to share and then select 'done'

I was a bit unsure if it would work so I only sent 26 photos to begin with.

I then opened the emails on his iphone 6 and you see a message asking you to subscribe to the album.

Click on the 'shared' cloud icon at the bottom of your photo library page and you'll see a box with the photos. Bear with it. To begin with the box was white - it took a while to download all the pictures and they seem to appear in a mixed order but eventually they will all appear.

To send another set of photos, go into the 'shared' cloud icon again and it will show your previous shared album. Below it, you will see a pale grey box with a blue cross and 'New Shared Stream' next to it. Click on that and start compiling your next set.

The second time, I sent 36 photos from the iphone 4 to the iphone 6 and it took a bit longer. I was beginning to panic but they've eventually all arrived.

Sorry this is a bit waffly and I'm trying to remember how it worked because now I've set it up once it's easier. I now have hundreds more photos to send over but hopefully it will continue to work and I plan to send a larger amount next time.

Good luck!